# increment number inside a sed expression mac osx

Tags: linux, macos, shell, sed, scripting

So here's my sed expression:

```
sed -E -i -e  '
  /<dependencies>/, /<\/dependencies>/ {
    /<dependency>/ {
      N
      /<groupId>'"$list"'</ {
        N
        /<artifactId>'"$artifactList"'</{
          N
          /<version>[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+<\/version>/ {
            s/(<version>[0-9]+\.)([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+(<\/version>)/\1\2.0\3/
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }'
```

I want to increase the min version number (1.2.4 -> 1.3.0)... what I'm able to achieve so far is to increase the patch number (1.2.4 -> 1.2.0)

I've tried several different things but it's not working for some reason. Also, Im looking for something that'll run both on a MacOSX as well as in linux.

Thanks! (P.S., I'm one day into shell scripting)

Comment: Does it have to be sed? Sed's good, but it's not a general purpose scripting language and it's not good at adding numbers. Awk or perl are the venerable contenders in this category, but there are many others that will do the job easily, like python, ruby, kotlin, ...

Comment: I'm so new to this thing, I'm unsure how to mix and match all of these scripting languages, if you can help me out in putting it at the right place I don't mind at all. Thank you!

Comment: Awk and perl have an advantage for you that the search/replace syntax is very similar to sed's. Perl is more general-purpose, more powerful and (in my experience) more headache-inducing. Awk, like sed, is aimed mostly as transforming streams of characters and adds some "ordinary" programming features like variables. If you're not interested in learning a full programming language and want to leverage the scripting you've already learned, pick one of those to write your script in.

Comment: You are parsing/modifying xml with sed? That can only go wrong. Use a programming language like Python or Perl which supports libraries to work with xml

Comment: Use `xmlstarlet`.